# Swift table, losing rows selected but not visibles

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I have a very stupid problem, but I tried several tips without results. I need a selective list in relation a large table (some rows ticked).

In the code, a fragment with the more consistent idea, but this list only the "visible" rows, if you choose the first and the lasts, my loop list only the rows visible on the screen. Below I listed the results, 0,1,2 are selected but not listed.

Thank you!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTableList.setEditing(true, animated: true) // show tick
    myTableList.delegate = self
    myTableList.dataSource = self
    myTableList.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
...
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("selected \(indexPath.item)")
}
@IBAction func listme(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    for i in 0..<myTableList.numberOfSections {
        for j in 0..<myTableList.numberOfRowsInSection(i) {
            print("cell #: \(j)")
            if let cell = myTableList.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: j, inSection: i)) {
                print("cell \(j) \(cell.selected)")
            }
        }
    }
} 


@ === console results === @
selected 0
selected 1
selected 2
selected 13
selected 14
selected 15
cell #: 0
cell #: 1
cell #: 2
cell #: 3
cell #: 4
cell #: 5
cell #: 6
cell #: 7
cell 7 false
cell #: 8
cell 8 false
cell #: 9
cell 9 false
cell #: 10
cell 10 false
cell #: 11
cell 11 false
cell #: 12
cell 12 false
cell #: 13
cell 13 true
cell #: 14
cell 14 true
cell #: 15
cell 15 true
===========================
```

Comment: Since cells are just views on your data and are reused, you cannot use the cell object itself to track state; once the cell is offscreen, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will return `nil`. Track your selections in an `IndexSet` or use the `indexPathsForSelectedRows` property of the table view

Comment: Thank you PaulW11, some times we don't see the obvious :)

This codes to reset the accessoryType, inducted me to the error:
if let cell = myTableList.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: j, inSection: i)) {cell.accessoryType = .None}

Answer (score 0):

Following the Pauls suggestion, I changed to:

```
var cellchecked: [DarwinBoolean] = []

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("checked \(indexPath.item)")
    cellchecked[indexPath.item] = true
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("none \(indexPath.item)")
        cellchecked[indexPath.item] = false
}
```

A simple code in my report solved the question, thank you guys!

```
if cellchecked[j] { .... }
```